# KineticJS drawScene method stops workgin after some time

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

In my application I draw some images that can be hidden from canvas by clicking them.
and I've encountered an error in my clients browsers (opera and safai)
After a sometime (2 to 5 minutes) of continuous clicking to those images, they've just stopped reacting on clicks.

the code looks like this:

```
this.selectItem = function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var addon = evt.targetNode;
    var current_avatar = avatars.avatar_list['avatar_'+addon.attrs.avatar_id];
    if(current_avatar.editable){
        if(!addon.attrs.addon_isbase){
            if(addon.attrs.addon_cattype !== 1){
                current_avatar.stage.remove(addon);
                /*addon.visible(false);*/
                current_avatar.stage.drawScene();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you provide any fiddle? Why are you using `drawScene`, but not `draw`?

Comment: I can provide a jsfiddle but it would not be informative because logic is complicate, and, as i said this bug is not 100% reproducible. I'll try to replace drawScene with draw and see what happens

Comment: Nope is did not work. I've change the drawScene to draw but the bug is still there.

Comment: It fact, now I'm doing full rewrite of scene. e.g. clearing all images, loading them once more from site and drawing. But the bug is still appearing